# progressively convert from javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, migration

Having an existing - heavy loaded -set of web pages full of plain vanilla Javascript code I want to progressively use jQuery by replacing some of the functions as needed.

In other terms I'm hoping that jQuery won't force me to rewrite the whole thing from scratch! If I'm right:

So  there are several existing JavaScript linked files (of mine) in a typical document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Play/DragDrop6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Play/aHand6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vstatus = "bid";
    var curtop = 0;
    var curleft = 0;
    var curwidth = 0;
    var curheight = 0;

    function return2Url() {
        history.go(-1);
    }

    function showSomethingb() {
        /...                  } </script></head><body>....
```

The question is: How do I add the jQuery.min.js library to that document and where do I put the $(document).ready(function()...

Say I want to rewrite the function showSomethingb() in jQuery style, where do I put it?

Comment: Your function as-is doesn't have anything that can be converted to use jQuery.

Comment: Nothing in that code would change if you added jQuery to the page. jQuery is not a language.  jQuery is a Javascript library that makes it easier to do lots of things in the context of a webpage.  I think you are WAY overthinking this.

Comment: http://think2loud.com/576-jquery-101-adding-jquery-to-your-website/ check how to use jquery in httml.as @ALex Wayne suggested nothing will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the link to the jquery library like you would any other javascript file.

Generally I do this first out of all my Js files so that it is available from the start.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.{version}.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Play/DragDrop6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Play/aHand6.js"></script>
```

Then, you are good to go.

You can use `$(document).ready(function()` on any (or every) page when you want something to execute once the whole page is loaded. But jquery is not limited to that. You can use it anywhere.

However it makes sense to put at least most of you JS code in one place.

So you code could become:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var vstatus = "bid";
    var curtop = 0;
    var curleft = 0;
    var curwidth = 0;
    var curheight = 0;

    function return2Url() {
        history.go(-1);
    }

    function showSomethingb() {
    } 

};
```

The rest is up to you on how you want to style and write your JS syntax.

The [jquery docs](http://jquery.com/)  are great.

Comment: Note however that if `return2Url` is being used in an `onclick=` then you can't place it in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Yup, the above is an example only. I wouldn't define my JS in this way.

Answer (score 1):

General best practice rule... add javascript to the end of the page where possible .... just before the closing `</body>` tag.

**How do I add the jQuery.min.js library to that document?**

Before all of your code. e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   //Then the rest of your code
</script>
```

**where do I put the $(document).ready(function()?**

Before the code you want to excute (but after the library above) when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Perform when document is ready
});
```

For your funciton I would write it as...

`var showSomethingb = function(){ //Your function };`

But there are different ways of doing this.

Comment: Be sure to load jQuery at the end of your page (before your closing `</body>` tag, but also before any other jQuery.

Comment: @AdamD Yes I agree I always add it to the bottom of the page. I will update answer.

Comment: ...and you should try to load jQuery from a Hosted CDN rather than from your server.

Comment: @AdamD I prefer to have everything on the one server... I know having it on a CDN is that fraction a bit quicker but if for some reason it goes down (I know with Google... etc it's highly unlikely) but no page is just as a bad as a page that doesn't function properly.

Comment: If that's the case, I would load my JS like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CppAH/  This loads from the CDN by default, but if for some reason it fails, it will load from your local server.

Answer (score 0):

First you should ask yourself do you really want to do this.

Technically, Jquery is javascript  …its like a shorthand notation of it.

So taking time to convert something you’ve already written in longhand into shorthand may not be a good use of your time.

If you’re looking to improve your js code, a better approach maybe to look at javascript best practices such as 
1. putting all code at the bottom of the body to ensure the UI loads first
2. minification to lighten the load
3. patterns like the module pattern
...I think you’ll find that more beneficial.

But if you’re sure, you need to do it manually (there is no tool that I’m aware of)
A great place to start is w3schools, you can play around with it too ..
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just by the by,

you can make that first line much shorter by using the shorthand for `$(document).ready(handler);` which is simply `$(handler);`.

So for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

becomes

```
$(function(){
    // your code
});
```

and will work the same. Yey!

For more information see:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/